# "ReferenceError: angular is not defined" while creating a separate file for angular controller script

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, webstorm

I am trying a basic node.js express app in webstorm and the following code is index.ejs file. the script that I kept inside comment section works completely while kept in this file but when I tried to keep the controller in a seperate JS file named personalController.js file is shows "ReferenceError: angular is not defined".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  <p> Try to change the name</p>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    First Name:<input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>

    <!--Full Name:{{fullName()}}-->
<p ng-bind="fullName"></p>

  </div>


    <script src="./personalController.js"></script>
<!--<script>-->

    <!--var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);-->

    <!--app.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {-->
        <!--$scope.firstName="jhon";-->
        <!--$scope.lastName="cena";-->
        <!--$scope.fullName=function () {-->
            <!--return $scope.firstName+ " "+ $scope.lastName;-->
        <!--};-->
    <!--});-->


<!--</script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include the angular script in the head, not floating in the HTML document. That might solve the issue.

Comment: tried it and it didn't work. the problem appears when I tried to put the script in separate file and the error points to the line "var myNgApp = angular.module('myApp', []);"

Comment: Can you update your code? You're likely calling your "var myNgApp = angular.module('myApp', []);", before angular has been initialized. Make sure the script containing it, is called after angular itself.